# Redirect SF1 Action to newly edited record based on executed javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, custom-button, publisher-action

We've recently had to start converting all our Javascript OnClick buttons to SF1 actions for the the new lightning UI.  This is some of the code I've converted.  It allows me to change the 'Status' of this record (which is a read-only custom field), but it redirects me to a new blank 'edit' page.  From there I would need to hit the 'Cancel' button and refresh the page to get the value to show up correctly.  Please, I need help on correcting the window location and have it redirect to the new 'version' of the record, or just refresh the page record itself.  Thanks ahead of time for any input.

**Old JavaScript OnClick Code:**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")} 
var newRecords = []; 
var e = new sforce.SObject("Event"); 
e.id ="{!Event.Id}"; 
e.Status__c = "Cancelled"; 
newRecords.push(e); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

**New JavaScript Code for SF1 Action within a VF Page (issue):**

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" >
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js"/>
    <script>   
        sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";        
        var newRecords = []; 
        var e = new sforce.SObject("Event"); 
        e.id ="{!Event.Id}"; 
        e.Status__c = "Cancelled"; 
        newRecords.push(e); 
        result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Screenshots of the issues I'm encountering:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ndAz.jpg

Comment: Salesforce1 navigation dictates you should use `sforce.one.navigateToSObject([RECORD_ID_HERE]);` for navigation. You might be able to use something along `Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}}); ` to refresh the record.

Comment: @AntonioManente Please add that as an answer .I see that as an answer .Thanks

Comment: @MohithShrivastava done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm) and [here (more useful methods)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)
It dictates that you use the method:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject([RECORD_ID_HERE]);
```

To navigate to the SObject.

For your case, use:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject(result[0].id);
```

I've also used:

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});
```

to refresh an object in salesforce1/lightning (should work if you're on the object's detail page, which seems not to be the case for you).

Comment: Would I use the 1st method or both?  I just tried both and with no luck.  Now it no longer changes the value.

        sforce.one.navigateToSObject([00U]);
        Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});

Comment: You would use one, the first is what's documented for Salesforce1 so I'd use that. This is updating a single record? Or could this be a bulk operation. @JoshuaDavis

Comment: sforce.one.navigateToSObject([RECORD_ID_HERE],'detail');Use your record Id appropriately .

Comment: This would be to just update a single record on the event object. @AntonioManente

Comment: @JoshuaDavis See my edit, that should work for you. One thing to note, remember that Javascript IS case sensitive so be sure to double check everything.

Comment: @AntonioManente - I have seen your edit and applied it.  Same issue.  It'll change the value but still show the edit page as shown in the imgur link above.  I am refreshing from the object record detail page. (1st image).  So I should use Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});   instead?

Comment: @JoshuaDavis I'm surprised that doesn't work as expected, I'd give the second one a shot as well. I'm assuming there are no Js errors right?

Comment: @AntonioManente The VF page compiler hasn't detected any errors. Will try the 2nd one. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe the compiler will pick up Javascript errors, you'd have to look at the console to check (F12 in chrome)

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at:
[http://imgur.com/jvHMyn8](http://imgur.com/jvHMyn8)

Comment: @AntonioManente - This is what the console is telling me: [http://imgur.com/Xc4xbUs](http://imgur.com/Xc4xbUs)

Comment: @JoshuaDavis Sorry, you'll need to include this `<script src="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js"/>` to use that.

Comment: @AntonioManente - That did the trick!  Works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help! @JoshuaDavis